# Basic evaluation of a limit 2 e

Tags: limits

How would evaluate the the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {1}{n^{\frac{2}{n}}}$$

Would $n^{\frac{2}{n}} = n^0$ If this can not be evaluated like this, could I use l'hopitals rule, and if so how?

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\frac{1}{n}=x$ (assuming it exists), then the limit in question is just $\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: Did you understand the answers of your question before. You are doing the same mistake!

Comment: how would I use lhopitals rule then?

Comment: Nobody told you to apply L'Hospital...

Comment: i am not sure with the exponents

Comment: Just to clear it up for you so that **you do not make the same mistake as last time** (because we want you to grow, not rely on us), it is never the case that we can simply say $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)^{g(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)^{\lim_{k\to\infty}g(k)}$$Especially if it returns indefinite forms.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$1 \leqslant n^{1/n} = \exp\left( \frac{\log n}{n}\right) = \exp\left( \frac{2\log \sqrt{n}}{n}\right) \leqslant \exp\left( \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{n}\right) = \exp\left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

Similar to RRL's:

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+\frac1{n^{1/2}})^n
\ge 1+\frac{n}{n^{1/2}}
\gt n^{1/2}
$.

Raising to the
$2/n$ power,
$n^{1/n}
\le (1+\frac1{n^{1/2}})^2
=1+\frac{2}{n^{1/2}}+\frac1{n}
<1+\frac{3}{n^{1/2}}
$.

Therefore
$n^{2/n}
<(1+\frac{3}{n^{1/2}})^2
=1+\frac{3}{n^{1/2}}+\frac{9}{n}
=1+\frac{12}{n^{1/2}}
$.

Note:
It is possible to show
by similar elementary methods that,
for any integer $k > 1$,
there is a $c(k)$ such that
$n^{1/n}
< 1+\frac{c(k)}{n^{1-1/k}}
$
for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I will show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^\frac{1}{n}=1$.  Then from the continuity of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ at $x=1$, it will follow that The limit in question is equal to $1$.

Let us write $x_n=n^\frac{1}{n}-1$.  Note that $x_n\geq0$ for all $n\geq1$. Then we have
$$n=(x_n+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x_n^k\geq1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x_n^2,$$
so that
$$0\leq x_n\leq\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\to0$$
as $n\to\infty$.  Thus $0=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(n^\frac{1}{n}-1\right)$ and therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^\frac{1}{n}=1$.